# A Rodrigues-Like Formula for $\mathrm{exp}:\mathrm{SO}(2)\to\mathrm{SO}(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

If Α a skew-symmetric matrix:
\begin{equation*}
A =  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -ω \\
ω & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Show, using Taylor, that:

\begin{equation*}
e^{AΘ} =  \begin{bmatrix}
  cosωθ & -sinωθ \\
sinωθ & cosωθ
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

i tried that:
$$e^{AΘ} = 1+\frac{(AΘ)}{1!}+\frac{({AΘ})^2}{2!}+...$$
but i'm not sure how can i continue in order to export the above matrix.
For SO(3), the procedure is defined,but for SO(2)?

Comment: Hint : diagonalize $A$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @Widawensen: In your edit the operator `\cos` got replaced by text `cos` (as also with $\sin \omega \theta$), which I suspect you will agree harms readability.  Shouldn't we put the slashes back?

Comment: @hardmath It was not me who changed that. I'm only added tag..

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Write $A =  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -\omega \\
\omega & 0
\end{bmatrix} \ \ $ as $A=\ \  \omega\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

Observe pattern which have the consecutive powers of $A$.

$A^2=\ \  \omega^2\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$,

$A^3=\ \  \omega^3\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,

$A^4=\ \  \omega^4\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\omega^4I$,

$A^5=\ \  \omega^5 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ ...

Probably now you see what is the form of the next powers - here we have only four types of $2 \times 2$ matrices multiplied by the $k$-th power of $\omega$ which can be appropriately grouped together ...

Comment: @Anna Have you finished the proof? See also that listed above matrices are in fact rotations by appropriately angle $90^\circ, 180^\circ, 270^\circ, 360^\circ, etc $. This is characteristic for powers of skew-symmetric matrix - such kind of cyclicity. The 4 matrices can be also divided into two groups: symmetric ( diagonal) and skew-symmetric ones...Group summands according to this characteristics.

Comment: @Anna I'm assuming also that you know series, otherwise see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions